# beautiful soup find link in a table by specifying two things

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do i get the resulting url: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391718000094/0001633917-18-000094-index.htm

...from this page ...

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001633917&owner=exclude&count=40

... by specifing `date = '2018-04-25` and I want `8-k` for Filing? Do I loop though or is there a one liner code that will get me the result?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import requests

date='2018-04-25'
CIK='1633917'

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=' + CIK + '&owner=exclude&count=100'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
a=soup.find('table', class_='tableFile2').findAll('tr')
for i in a:
    print i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one liner code to get what you want. You'll have to loop through the rows and then check if the values match.

But, there is a slightly better approach which narrows down the rows. You can directly select the rows which match one of the values. For example, you can select all the rows which have `date = '2018-04-25'` and then check if the Filing matches.

**Code:**

```
for date in soup.find_all('td', text='2018-04-25'):
    row = date.find_parent('tr')
    if row.td.text == '8-K':
        link = row.a['href']
        print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
/Archives/edgar/data/1633917/000163391718000094/0001633917-18-000094-index.htm
```

So, here, instead of looping over all the rows, you simply loop over the rows having the date you want. In this case, there is only one such row, and hence we loop only once.